# How to created a fixed width ouput with sqlcmd

Tags: sqlcmd

The following executes in our SQL 2008 R2 environment and everything works well.  Vendor executes on  SQL Server 2012 and formatting changes.

For example a simple select

```
Select '1',cast(RIGHT(replace(convert(varchar,[EMPL_EARNINGS].[PAY_PD_END_DT],112),'-',''),6) as CHAR(6))
```

I can't use `-W` because some fields are padded with spaces.

I select 3 different date fields with the same statement.
One is correct 6 characters wide, another is 8, and yet another is 9.

Batch file call is  `sqlcmd -S ServerName -i "c:\query\myquery.sql" -o "v:\Temp\myouput.dat" -h -1 -s""  -d"DBname"`.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the column widths matched the width of the column names, even though I was using -h-1.  Not sure why it worked on our version but not the vendors.

Quick fix was to shorten all column names to <= desired column width.

Curious to discover the REAL fix?